# how to set and check recurring payment on paypal pro sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal pro payments and I want to use recurring payment with this. How I can get this.

I have set Billing Period - Day and Billing Frequency - 2;

what does it mean?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billing Cycle for Paypal:

The billing frequency specifies the number of billing periods that make up the billing cycle.
if the billing period is Month and the billing frequency is 2, the billing cycle will be two months. If the billing period is Week and the billing frequency is 6, the payments will be scheduled every 6 weeks.

In your case,
billing period is Day and the billing frequency is 2, the billing cycle will be two day.

Comment: is it never ending billing cycle?

Comment: you want to cancel it?

Comment: just asking who can cancel the recurring payment customer or merchant?

Comment: follow these steps you may want to cancel it - http://www.wikihow.com/Cancel-a-Recurring-Payment-in-PayPal